# Maintaining a count of divs in var i

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've created 4 divs and allotted a variable 'i' which indicates the number of divs. If I delete a div, the variable 'i' should decrease without refreshing the webpage(dynamically). [image: This is what I mean]

Here is the code

```
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '#new-mcq', function () {
    if (i == 0)
        $(".insert-question-container").html('');

    i++;
    createdDivs++;
    mcqCount++;
    $(".insert-question-container").append('<div class="add-question-new" id="' + i + '"><div class="add-question-close"><span class="close-btn-mcq" id="' + i + '"></span></div><div class="add-question-name">'+i+'Multiple Choice Question</div><div class="add-question-text"><textarea class="inputs-textarea" name="mcq-question-'+i+'" placeholder="Enter Question here" name="mcq-question' + mcqCount + '"></textarea></div><div class="add-question-option"><input type="text" class="inputs-correct" name="mcq-choice-'+i+'.c" placeholder="Enter correct answer" name="mcq-answer' + mcqCount + '"/></div><div class="add-question-option"><input type="text"class="inputs" name="mcq-choice-'+i+'.1" placeholder="Other Choice 1" name="mcq-answer' + mcqCount + '"/></div><div class="add-question-option"><input type="text"class="inputs" name="mcq-choice-'+i+'.2" placeholder="Other Choice 2" name="mcq-answer' + mcqCount + '"/></div><div class="add-question-option"><input type="text"class="inputs" name="mcq-choice-'+i+'.3" placeholder="Other Choice 3" name="mcq-answer' + mcqCount + '"/></div></div>').show('slow');
    //alert("MCQ: "+mcqCount);   
    });
});


$(document).on('click', '.close-btn-mcq', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var className = $(".add-question-new").attr("id");
    $("#" + id).remove();
    //alert(id);
    deletedDivs++;
    mcqCount--;
    i--;
    //alert("i = " + i);
    //alert("mcq = " + mcqCount);
    if (createdDivs == deletedDivs)
        i = 0;

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="insert-question-container">

</div>
<div class="add-question-btn-container">
            <p align="left">Add Question: </p>            
            <button class="btn-newquestion" type="button" id="new-mcq">Multiple Choice</button>
            <button class="btn-newquestion" type="button" id="new-tf">True / False</button>
            <button class="btn-newquestion" type="button" id="new-sa">Short Answer</button>
            <button class="btn-newquestion" type="button" id="new-mtc">Match Column</button>               
       </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML/CSS required to reproduce this or a demo..?

Comment: This code looks pretty straight forward.  It there a question?  What is it doing wrong, not doing, or what error are you getting that you need assistance with?

Comment: If I add 4 multiple choice question divs, and remove one from between, the last multiple choice question should dynamically change it's value to 3 without refreshing the page.

Comment: This question needs a better title for future visitors. Obviously JS vars can be changed without a page refresh, everyone knows that, and is not really an issue here.  The issue seems to be counting divs or maintaining a count of divs in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had three main problems that I discovered.

1. The variables you are incrementing were undefined see the changes at the top of the    javascript code. Without any initial value then there is no way to increment or decrement the values. See patch 1
2. You had no content for your close question button(I added an X to click on). See Patch 2
3. You needed a way to update question numbers. I added an each function to update the 
   question numbers. See patch 3

link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/bjenoe0c/

Javascript code changes:

```
    var i = 0;

/*begin patch # 1: You variable were not defined*/

//define createdDivs<-fixes not defined error
var createdDivs;

//define mcqCount<-fixes not defined error
var mcqCount;

//define deletedDivs<-fixes not defined error
var deletedDivs;

/*end patch 1*/

$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '#new-mcq', function () {
    if (i == 0)
        $(".insert-question-container").html('');

    i++;
    createdDivs++;
    mcqCount++;

    /*patch 2: added text to close-btn-mcq, it can not be clicked
      if there is no content
    */
    $(".insert-question-container").append('<div class="add-question-new" id="' + i + '"><div class="add-question-close"><span class="close-btn-mcq" id="' + i + '">|X|</span></div><div class="add-question-name">'+i+'Multiple Choice Question</div><div class="add-question-text"><textarea class="inputs-textarea" name="mcq-question-'+i+'" placeholder="Enter Question here" name="mcq-question' + mcqCount + '"></textarea></div><div class="add-question-option"><input type="text" class="inputs-correct" name="mcq-choice-'+i+'.c" placeholder="Enter correct answer" name="mcq-answer' + mcqCount + '"/></div><div class="add-question-option"><input type="text"class="inputs" name="mcq-choice-'+i+'.1" placeholder="Other Choice 1" name="mcq-answer' + mcqCount + '"/></div><div class="add-question-option"><input type="text"class="inputs" name="mcq-choice-'+i+'.2" placeholder="Other Choice 2" name="mcq-answer' + mcqCount + '"/></div><div class="add-question-option"><input type="text"class="inputs" name="mcq-choice-'+i+'.3" placeholder="Other Choice 3" name="mcq-answer' + mcqCount + '"/></div></div>').show('slow');
    //alert("MCQ: "+mcqCount);   
    });
});


$(document).on('click', '.close-btn-mcq', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var className = $(".add-question-new").attr("id");
    $("#" + id).remove();
    //alert(id);
    deletedDivs++;
    mcqCount--;
    i--;

    /*patch 3: add each function to change question numbers
    */
    $(".add-question-name").each(function(i){//begin each function

        //update the question number
        $(this).html((i + 1) + " Multiple Choice Question");

    });//end each function


    //debug only
    alert("i = " + i);
    //alert("mcq = " + mcqCount);



    if (createdDivs == deletedDivs)
        i = 0;

});
```

Comment: See your jsfiddle, add 3 divs and remove div number 2. The remaining 2 divs will have name as 1Multiple Choice Question and 3Multiple Choice Question. My problem is that I want to have there names as 1Multiple Choice Question and 2MultipleChoice Question

Comment: check out the fiddle now. I added a function to update your page numbers after removing a question. I hope it helps.

Comment: You just made my life easier.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just count the number of DIVs you have?

```
$(".add-question-new").length
```

will get you a count of elements with that class.

```
$("DIV.add-question-new").length
```

will get you a count of only divs with that class.

```
$("DIV.add-question-new.deleted").length
```

will get you a count of DIVS with the class of `.add-question-new` and `.deleted`.  So, if they tag it as deleted, you just apply a deleted class to it.  It'd look like

```
<DIV class="add-question-new deleted">
```

then with CSS you can either keep it around or remove it   `{DIV.add-question-new.deleted:  display:none;}`     (or do nothing).

That way you're depending on actual numbers of elements on the page --  instead of tracking a sort-of-maybe-right-maybe-not counter that's supposed to be a representation of what you can determine by just studying the DOM.